# Basic algorithm for a cipher encryption not working as intended alphabet array

Tags: java, arrays

So, I have this algorithm for a cipher in Java. I have an alphabet array:

```
char[] alphabet = {'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y'};
```

And also a table that stores characters (based on the input). This isn't that important given that I've checked numerous times and it stores the characters exactly as intended. What I have below is a code so that every letter on a Y axis's letter value in the alphabet array is moved Y+1 times to the right on alphabet's "axis", value which if is over 25 goes back to the first value. Meaning that if 'A' were at Y=0 it would change from the value 1 on the alphabet axis to 2, meaning 'B', and 'X' at Y=2 would have the value of 24 changed to 27, and because it is over 25 it would turn into 27-25=2, 'B'. Why is the code below outputting 'Z' for the letter 'A' located at X=0 Y=0?

```
for(int p = 0; p < number; p++) {
            for(int q = 0; q < number; q++) {
                for(int r = 0; r < 26; r++) {
                    if(table[q][p] == alphabet[r]) {
                        table[q][p] = alphabet[(r+p+1)%26];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to run the program with a debugger and step through it to see where the behaviour deviates from your expectations.

Comment: It would be great if you could post desired result and result you get from the data you provided.

Comment: Is this some [Floyd Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) exact match algo implementation. I really do miss how the matrix is populated and what does XY alphabet axis means.

Comment: @dbl ehm, what? why should this question be related to a graph algorithm? it's all about encryption of a text

Comment: @AKSW since the question is tagged as (java, arrays) it should mean that you don't need any further context to understand it... Which is not the case for me ;) I don't say it's a bit of pain to make a quick research on the topic, just I won't spend these 10 mins on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only now realised my issue.
The code would work, and change 'A' to 'B'. But it could keep testing for the r values from 2 to 25 whether that table slot would equal to the next number. And of course it did. The character, now 'B', equals to the index 2 of the alphabet array, and so on until it would finally end, turning into 'Z'. All I had to do then was add `break;` to the last `for` loop.
Thanks for the help all the same!

Answer (score 0):

the code you added will produce letter 'Z' for 'A' when X=0, and Y=0. I assume that [q] and [p] are equal to 0

Probleme lies here:

```
if(table[q][p] == alphabet[r]) {
     table[q][p] = alphabet[(r+p+1)%26];
 }
```

If table[0][0] holds "A" value this condition is true when r variable is equal to 25. Because in your alphabet array 'A' letter is under index 25.Then:

```
table[q][p] = alphabet[(r+p+1)%26];
```

So table[0][0] will equal to alphabet[(25+0+1)%26] and 26%26 is 0.

```
table[q][p] = alphabet[0]
```

Which is 'Z' letter in your array.

*Update:* try this:

```
    Character[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    Character[][] table = {{'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'}, {'e', 'f'}};

    for (int x = 0; x < table.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < table[x].length; y++) {
            int index = Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(table[x][y]);
            table[x][y] = alphabet[(index + y + 1) % 26];
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's what I don't understand. Why would 'A' (all letters ever mentioned are lowercase, don't take into consideration the idea of uppercase) be in place 25 in the alphabet array? Doesn't it follow 'Z'? Wouldn't its index be 1?

Comment: Let me understand what you expect. You have letter 'A' in [0][0] after the algorythm ends it should be 'B' ? And you have 'A' as well but under [0][1] you should get 'C'?

Comment: Yes, that's the main idea

Comment: I tried what you last recommended. Did not work, I did however remove the  y axis (or p), and it turns out for every character in the table Z gets outputted in this case. I'll try figuring something out, and update you if I am still confused. I'll cancel the question if I manage to work everything out

Comment: I figured it out!